# My database is fetching duplicate records when i am working with server 2003 in mysql

Tags: sql, database

```
SELECT EMPID,e.CUR_VC_FIRSTNAME_NN,d.DEPTNAME,LTID,FROMLEAVEDATE,FROMLEAVETYPE,TOLEAVEDATE,TOLEAVETYPE,NUM_LEV_DAYS 
FROM lmsdb.leaves l,lmsdb.department d,lmsdb.emp_pas_data e 
WHERE l.EMPID=e.cur_c_empno_pk 
    AND d.DEPTID=e.CUR_C_DEPT_CD_CFK 
    AND empid IN (SELECT cur_c_empno_pk 
                  FROM lmsdb.emp_pas_data 
                  WHERE uni_vc_unit_desc_nn='Hyderabad') 
    AND LEV_STATUS='2' 
    AND TOLEAVEDATE>'2013-06-27' 
    AND FROMLEAVEDATE<'2013-07-28' 
ORDER BY d.DEPTNAME,EMPID ASC;
```

This is query i am working with server 2003. The same query when i work with window xp mysql it working properly.

Comment: Could you clarify? What is "server 2003"? What version(s) of MySQL are you using?

Comment: in windows server 2003 i installed mysql server5.5 and the same version i installed in windows xp also. when i am working with that query in xp it is showing single record when i export to excel sheet.but the same query when i work with server it is showing two time each record.because form data base it is fetching two times a record

Comment: please any one can help me on this

Comment: I cant see anything that jumps out as the cause to this but have you tried putting a distinct clause on your select?

Comment: So, is your source data definitely the same in both databases? What do your query results actually look like? Which source rows are contributing to the results? The most likely cause is simply that there's one more row of data in the database on the 2003 machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EMPID,e.CUR_VC_FIRSTNAME_NN,d.DEPTNAME,LTID,FROMLEAVEDATE,FROMLEAVETYPE,TOLEAVEDATE,TOLEAVETYPE,NUM_LEV_DAYS    
FROM lmsdb.leaves l,  
     lmsdb.department d,  
     lmsdb.emp_pas_data e   
WHERE l.EMPID=e.cur_c_empno_pk   
        AND d.DEPTID=e.CUR_C_DEPT_CD_CFK   
        AND e.uni_vc_unit_desc_nn='Hyderabad')   
        AND LEV_STATUS='2'   
        AND TOLEAVEDATE>'2013-06-27'   
        AND FROMLEAVEDATE<'2013-07-28'  
ORDER BY d.DEPTNAME,EMPID ASC;
```

Your query looks correct. You should check duplicate rows in either table lmsdb.leaves or in lmsdb.emp_pas_data